# Click Event Listener on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Wrote the entire code as suggested but doesn't seem to word. grid is my 2d array containing all the words of 'words' array plus random letters in empty squares. But code doesn't work. Unable to debug. Needed help.Thanks in advance.

```
function game(grid){
var words =['HELLO', 'CYCLE','APPLE','COOK', 'OPERA','COURT','HOUSE','NEWEST'];
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas1");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
ctx1.font = "14px verdana";

$results = $("#results");
$heading = $("#heading");
var rowCount = 15;
var rowHeight = 30;
var colCount = 15;
var colWidth = 30;


// drag related variables
var startX, startY, mouseX, mouseY;
var isDown = false;


// listen for mouse events on the canvas
$("#canvas1").mousedown(function (e) {
handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvas2").mouseup(function (e) {
handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvas3").mouseout(function (e) {
handleMouseOut(e);
});

// draw the puzzle grid on the canvas
drawRect();

//draw lettered grid
function drawRect() {
ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (var j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        ctx1.rect(i * colWidth, j * rowHeight, colWidth, rowHeight);
        ctx1.stroke();
        ctx1.fillText(grid[i][j].toUpperCase(), i * colWidth + 5, j * (rowHeight) +   20);
    }
}
}
// set the starting X/Y of the drag on mousedown
function handleMouseDown(e) {

// tell the browser we're handling this event
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

// redraw the puzzle grid on the canvas
drawRect();

// start the drag
isDown = true;
}

// set the ending X/Y of the drag on mouseup
function handleMouseUp(e) {

// tell the browser we're handling this event
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

// set the ending X/Y
mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

// done with the drag
isDown = false;

// check if the drag-selected word is part to the puzzle
checkForWord();
}
// cancel the drag if the mouse exits the canvas
function handleMouseOut(e) {
// tell the browser we're handling this event
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
// moved out of the canvas, stop the drag
isDown = false;
}


function checkForWord() {

// get the starting & ending grid-cell
// that the user dragged across
var startCol = parseInt(startX / colWidth);
var startRow = parseInt(startY / rowHeight);

var lastCol = parseInt(mouseX / colWidth);
var lastRow = parseInt(mouseY / rowHeight);

// get the word that the user dragged across
// by adding the letters from the starting cell
// to the ending cell
var word = [];;
var length = Math.max(Math.abs(startCol - lastCol) + 1, Math.abs(startRow - lastRow) +      1);
var dx = 0;
var dy = 0;
var x = startCol;
var y = startRow;
if (lastCol > startCol) {
    dx = 1;
}
if (lastCol < startCol) {
    dx = -1;
}
if (lastRow > startRow) {
    dy = 1;
}
if (lastRow < startRow) {
    dy = -1;
}i=0;
while (length > 0) {
    // add the letter in this grid-cell to the word
    word[i]= grid[y][x];
    // highlight the squares that the user selected
    ctx1.save();
    ctx1.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx1.globalAlpha = 0.25;
    ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    ctx1.fillRect((x) * colWidth + 2, (y) * rowHeight + 2, colWidth - 4, rowHeight -  4);
    ctx1.restore();
    // increment x/y/length for the next letter
    i++;
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    length--;
}

// reverse the word if dragged backwards
/*if (dx < 0 || dy < 0) {
    word.split('').reverse().join('');
}*/

// test if the word is a solution word assuming it's spelled frontwards
for(var index=0;index < words.length;i++){
   if(word === words[index])
     var found =1;  

}
if (found === 1){
$results.text("You just found: " + words[index]);}

else 
    {  
        $results.text("Sorry...Try Again.");
    }

}}
```

Comment: please take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814883/add-an-event-listener-to-a-drawn-object-on-html5-canvas), the keyword you should be looking for is "hittest"

Comment: But my squares aren't empty.They have letters within each.I have to get the squares selected along with the letters inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[ Updated answer based on new info from questioner ]**

To drag-select words in a word-search puzzle you need these capabilities:

- Define the grid and the letters inside each grid-square.
- Draw the grid-squares with the associated letters inside.
- Listen for mousedown events
- On mousedown begin the drag operation (save the starting X/Y mouse position)
- On mouseup end the drag operation (save the ending X/Y mouse position)
- Also on mouseup, check if the letter-squares between starting & ending mouse positions spell one of the remaining words in the puzzle
- If a correct puzzle word was selected, remove it from the list of puzzle words

Annotated code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Ud7R3/

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas related variables
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx1=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();
    ctx1.font="14px verdana";

    // puzzle related variables
    $results=$("#results");
    $puzzle=$("#puzzle");
    var rowCount=7;
    var rowHeight=40;
    var colCount=7;
    var colWidth=40;
    var puzzle="Popcorn tastes good with butter";
    var words=puzzle.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    var letters=['g','b','s','i','c','e','n','o','b','u','w','v','r','d','o','k','i','t','o','n','d','d','t','m','c','t','a','a','h','a','p','y','s','e','c','k','o','z','b','z','i','r','p','t','a','s','t','e','s'];
    $puzzle.text("Find: "+puzzle);


    // drag related variables
    var startX,startY,mouseX,mouseY;
    var isDown=false;

    // listen for mouse events on the canvas
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

    // draw the puzzle grid on the canvas
    drawRect();


    // draw lettered grid squares
    function drawRect(){
        ctx1.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var j=0;j<rowCount;j++){
            var letterRow=[];
            for(var i=0; i<colCount ;i++){
                ctx1.rect(i*colWidth,j*rowHeight,colWidth,rowHeight);
                ctx1.stroke();      
                ctx1.fillText(letters[j*colCount+i].toUpperCase(),i*colWidth+15,j*(rowHeight)+25);
            }
        }
    }

    // set the starting X/Y of the drag on mousedown
    function handleMouseDown(e){

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // redraw the puzzle grid on the canvas
      drawRect();

      // start the drag
      isDown=true;
    }

    // set the ending X/Y of the drag on mouseup
    function handleMouseUp(e){

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // set the ending X/Y
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // done with the drag
      isDown=false;

      // check if the drag-selected word is part to the puzzle
      checkForWord();


    }

    // cancel the drag if the mouse exits the canvas
    function handleMouseOut(e){
      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      // moved out of the canvas, stop the drag
      isDown=false;
    }

    function checkForWord(){

        // get the starting & ending grid-cell
        // that the user dragged across
        var startCol=parseInt(startX/colWidth);
        var startRow=parseInt(startY/rowHeight);
        var lastCol=parseInt(mouseX/colWidth);
        var lastRow=parseInt(mouseY/rowHeight);

        // get the word that the user dragged across
        // by adding the letters from the starting cell
        // to the ending cell
        var word="";
        var length=Math.max(Math.abs(startCol-lastCol)+1,Math.abs(startRow-lastRow)+1);
        var dx=0;
        var dy=0;
        var x=startCol;
        var y=startRow;
        if(lastCol>startCol){dx=1;}
        if(lastCol<startCol){dx=-1;}
        if(lastRow>startRow){dy=1;}
        if(lastRow<startRow){dy=-1;}
        while(length>0){
            // add the letter in this grid-cell to the word
            word+=letters[y*colCount+x];
            // highlight the squares that the user selected
            ctx1.save();
            ctx1.fillStyle="red";
            ctx1.globalAlpha=0.25;
            ctx1.globalCompositeOperation="destination-over";
            ctx1.fillRect((x)*colWidth+2,(y)*rowHeight+2,colWidth-4,rowHeight-4);
            ctx1.restore();
            // increment x/y/length for the next letter
            x+=dx;
            y+=dy;
            length--;
        }

        // reverse the word if dragged backwards
        if(dx<0 || dy<0){ word.split('').reverse().join(''); }

        // test if the word is a solution word assuming it's spelled frontwards
        var frontwards=words.indexOf(word.toLowerCase());

        // test if the word is a solution word assuming it's spelled backwards
        var backwards=words.indexOf(stringBackwards(word).toLowerCase());

        // if the selected word matches a puzzle word
        // tell the user they found the word an remove the word from the puzzle
        // if the selected word doesn't match any remaining puzzle word
        // tell the user to try again
        if(frontwards>=0 || backwards>=0){
            var index=Math.max(frontwards,backwards);
            $results.text("You just found: "+words[index]);
            words.splice(index,1);
            if(words.length>0){
                var remainingWords="Find:"
                for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
                    remainingWords+=" "+words[i];
                }
                $puzzle.text(remainingWords);
            }else{
                $puzzle.text("Congratulations...");
                $results.text("You found all the words in the puzzle!");    
            }

        }else{
            if(words.length>0){
                $results.text("Sorry...Try Again.");
            }
        }
    }

    function stringBackwards(s){
        return(s.split('').reverse().join(''));
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="puzzle">Find: Popcorn tastes good with butter</h3>
    <h4 id="results">Drag through the lettered squares</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for taking so much pain. I was suggested to using draw the grid and letters using easeljs as it has better drag options. Your answer has opened up ideas. I shall try to implement the drag and selection of words in grids using it.

Comment: Besides I am trying to make something like http://wordsearch.randomsaladgames.com/ It will be possible without easeljs  and ur code as help, right?

Comment: Your link is broken because it requires a login--but I know the idea of wordsearches.  I see you desire selection with dragging. I'm guessing you want the user to draw through a set of letters forming a word.  One problem with draw-selection on a grid occurs for diagonal selections.  Dragging across a diagonal corner can hit any of 3 neighboring grid-squares.  With EaselJS or with plain canvas you will have to develop logic of how to handle accidental selections on diagonal drags.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again. Its alot of help. I really hope I am not bugging you with silly questions. Bt since I am only learning and not an expert, I have made my words and  letters random, so I get a new puzzle with my words each time it loads. All letters in a 2d array. Ok there should be no problem. The last thing I needed was to is to kip the searched words highlighted and struck of from the list of words to find. Can it be done through css?

Comment: If you want to keep all the discovered words highlighted then just eliminate `drawRect` inside the handleMouseDown function.  My answer already removes discovered words from the word list at the top of the page (see the words after "Find:").  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Its not all the discovered words. Its the correct words that should be  highlighted from all chosen words. Removing drawRect will ultimately keep any word chosen to be highlighted.

Comment: I have confidence that you will be able to fix that small glitch.

Comment: okay.. thanq!! i have all my words to be searched on another canvas. When a word is found on this canvas, can i make it disappear on the other canvas. The one you did is amended the 'results' div right?

Comment: tried numerous things the whole day. Not able to fix the glitch :(

Comment: OK, just delay highlighting the grid-cells until you know the user's selection is one of the correct puzzle words. To do this: Pull the code relating to highlighting squares out of the while loop in checkForWord().  Create a similar while loop within the if-statement that knows the user has selected a correct word. Be sure to reset the x,y,length variables just prior to that similar loop (the loop depends on those x,y,length variables).