# JavaScript objects: 'addEventListener is not a function'

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas, mapping

I create an array of JavaScript objects called elements and loop through it in order to draw every one on a canvas as well as hooking up a few event handlers to it.  However, I get an error stating that

```
'Uncaught TypeError: elements[i].addEventListener is not a function'
```

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(onDocumentReady);
function onDocumentReady() {
    var COLOR_NORMAL = '#005A84';
    var COLOR_SELECTED = '#00F2F2';
    var COLOR_MOUSEOVER = '#5BA621';

    var canvas = document.getElementById("mapCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DiePrintList));
    var elem =
        canvas,
        left = elem.offsetLeft,
        top = elem.offsetTop,
        context = elem.getContext('2d'),
        elements = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        elements.push({
            color: '#0489B1',
            width: 15,
            height: 15,
            row: data[i].Row,
            col: data[i].Col,
            top: data[i].Row * 20,
            left: data[i].Col * 20
        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var hitElement = getHitElement(elements, event.pageX - left, event.pageY - top);
            hitElement.color = COLOR_SELECTED;
            drawElement(context, hitElement);
        }, false);
        elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
            var hitElement = getHitElement(elements, event.pageX - left, event.pageY - top);
            hitElement.color = COLOR_MOUSEOVER;
            drawElement(context, hitElement);
        }, false);
        elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
            var hitElement = getHitElement(elements, event.pageX - left, event.pageY - top);
            hitElement.color = COLOR_SELECTED;
            drawElement(context, hitElement);
        }, false);
        drawElement(context, elements[i]);
    }
}
function drawElement(context, element) {
    context.fillStyle = element.color;
    context.fillRect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
}
function getHitElement(elements, x, y) {
    var hitElement;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (y > elements[i].top && y < elements[i].top + elements[i].height && 
            x > elements[i].left && x < elements[i].left + elements[i].width) {
            hitElement = elements[i];
        }
    }
    return hitElement;
}
```

Why is it that I cannot hook up an event handler to each individual element?

Comment: "`anyFunction` is not a function" means that `anyFunction` is not part of the object from where its called.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your specific error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: elements[i].addEventListener is not a function'
```

is because `elements[i].addEventListener` is `undefined` and thus is not a function.  The reason it is `undefined` is because your `elements` array contains regular Javascript objects.  Those objects do not have a `.addEventListener()` method.  That is a method on DOM objects that are an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), not regular Javascript objects (unless you make your own method called `addEventListener` and add it to your Javascript objects).

Since I don't see a corresponding array of DOM elements in your code, it appears like you're trying to attach eventListeners to rectangles you draw on your Canvas which is not something you can do in that way.  T'he things you've drawn on a Canvas object are basically like a bitmap.  It doesn't retain a knowledge of objects you drew on it other than the resulting pixels.  You draw on it and the result is pixels on the canvas, not a persistent set of objects such as DOM objects.  If you want to later do hit testing versus things you drew on the canvas, then you'd have to put an eventListener on the canvas object itself to get the input event, keep track yourself of what object you drew where on the canvas and then when the event triggers on your canvas listener, you can do your own hit testing versus that data of what you put where.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an array of basic javascript objects. Which don't have the addEventListener method which are only used in [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) objects.

Look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814883/add-an-event-listener-to-a-drawn-object-on-html5-canvas) for an idea on how to do what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to attach `EventListener()` to objects that do not support events.

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> The event target may be an `Element` in a document, the `Document`
>   itself, a `Window`, or any other object that supports events (such as
>   `XMLHttpRequest`).

What you call `elements` does not match any of the above criteria.